# swap string value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field `cr_id` that is filled in like this:

```
| cr_id
-----------------------------------------
| [DL_KZ#123456789][ID#123456789]
| [DL_KZ#987654321][ID#987654321]
| [DL_KZ#987654321][ID#123456789,987654321]
```

But I need the ID field to be filled in first, and then the DL_KZ field:

```
    | cr_id
    -----------------------------------------
    | [ID#123456789][DL_KZ#123456789]
    | [ID#987654321][DL_KZ#987654321]
    | [ID#123456789,987654321][DL_KZ#987654321]
```

How it possible to do?

Comment: Will the input strings always have exactly two pairs of `[ ... ]`, with everything else inside one or the other of the bracket pairs, and will the two "tokens" always begin with `ID#` and `DL_KZ#` respectively? And will the order **always** be wrong, or might it be right in some rows but wrong in others, and you only need to switch in the wrong ones, not in **all** the input rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is using `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function in which the trick is to make the *replace_string* argument being composed of two backreferences **\2\1** with respect to this order in order to swap respective capture groups such as

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(cr_id,'^(\[.*\])(\[.*\])$','\2\1') 
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bded231bafd0e77be30d0236c5b6ed98)</kbd>

Comment: SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(cr_id,'^(\[.*\])(\[.*\])(\[.*\])(\[.*\])$','4\3\2\1')
FROM t1

Comment: Do u know why this is not working correctly?

Comment: Hi @SultanZhubaniyazov . Please ask another question for this new one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73358072/swap-string-value-in-oracle-2

Answer (score 1):

Simple & fast `substr + instr` combination:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (cr_id) as
  2    (select '[DL_KZ#123456789][ID#123456789]'           from dual union all
  3     select '[DL_KZ#987654321][ID#987654321]'           from dual union all
  4     select '[DL_KZ#987654321][ID#123456789,987654321]' from dual
  5    )
```

Query:

```
  6  select substr(cr_id, instr(cr_id, '[', 1, 2)) ||
  7         substr(cr_id, 1, instr(cr_id, ']')) result
  8  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ID#123456789][DL_KZ#123456789]
[ID#987654321][DL_KZ#987654321]
[ID#123456789,987654321][DL_KZ#987654321]

SQL>
```