# swap string value in oracle #2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I previously addressed with an identical question([swap string value in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73333725/swap-string-value-in-oracle/73337676?noredirect=1#comment129548849_73337676)) , but there is one more moment.

I have a field `cr_id` that is filled in like this:

```
| cr_id
-----------------------------------------
| [DL_KZ#123456789][ID#123456789][PART#1234567][NEXT_STEP#0]
```

But I need the `ID` field to be filled in first, and then the `DL_KZ` field, next `PART` AND `NEXT_STEP`

```
| cr_id
-----------------------------------------
[ID#123456789][DL_KZ#123456789][PART#1234567][NEXT_STEP#0]
```

I tried to modify this select:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(cr_id,'^(\[.*\])(\[.*\])$','\2\1')
```

But in the end, the order turned out to be different or even numbers appeared at the beginning of the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it contains 4 parts, not just two, so you have to reflect that in code:

```
SQL> with test (cr_id) as
  2    (select '[DL_KZ#123456789][ID#123456789][PART#1234567][NEXT_STEP#0]' from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(cr_id, '^(\[.*\])(\[.*\])(\[.*\])(\[.*\])$', '\2\1\3\4') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------
[ID#123456789][DL_KZ#123456789][PART#1234567][NEXT_STEP#0]

SQL>
```